# Best approach for distributing common data in server to desktop application spread globally

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

**The Scenario:** i have a common data used by desktop application spread globally. The common data will be changed in frequent manner which need to distributed to desktop application spread globally.

**Approaches**

1. Call to a web service from desktop application spread globally to get the common data every time for processing.
   **cons:** A server call a desktop every time is very costly operation.
2. Downloaded common data as a xml file into all desktop application spread globally and need to download changed data if any changes in common data (it should be an push technology)
   **cons:** If it is not push technology then it will be costly

Is there any push technology to handle the above scenario. (i.e., if any changes done in server then only down the changes)

which approach is good of the above or is there any approach better than this?

Comment: How much data?  How frequent are the changes?  Do multiple changes need to be handled as a single set?  What is the cost of failure, be it a client running with old common data or a client unable to get the latets common data?  Why do you think this is a suitable question for SO?

Comment: Defining a caching policy makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Is an if-modified-since http fetch too expensive?

Comment: @HABO: It will around 100 records. New data may be added at monthly once. multiple change are done in one shot. if client working with old data there may be some accuracy failures but the application works fine. The data will be synced when the client working with the application.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: there is Caching implemented in web service level (i.e., if there no data changes it will send it from cache other wise it will get it from db)

Comment: @KumaranT What you've described is an implementation of caching. But not a policy. A policy would describe when a request can be satisfied with a cached copy and when it needs to do a new request. Your comment response to HABO was actually pretty close. You can also have multiple policies (e.g. a weak reference to an in memory collection that gets re-populated from a serialized copy that gets refreshed from a web-service, etc.)

Comment: I have to agree with HABO though... this question might not be suited for SO, perhaps you might have better luck at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do the desktop applications modify the data or is it just something that
is defined by "the server" ?

If the server modifies the data and it's for read only use by the client
there are many options:

- You can store the data in something like a shared DropBox folder.
- You can add a method to your web service that returns a new GUID every time
  the data has changed, letting the client know the data should be downloaded again.
  Getting a single GUID from the server should not be expensive (especially compared to downloading all the data in one go)
- You could use something like RabbitMQ to fan out changes to all the clients (If having an open TCP connection is an option

If the desktop clients are allowed to modify the data and there is more than one client modifying that data at the same time you may want to take a completely different approach. But in that case there's not enough information in your question to really give you a good answer.